# Scikit-learn decision path

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I am following the below URL to predict a path taken in decision tree for a specific sample
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/tree/plot_unveil_tree_structure.html# 
This code given works fine with the example IRIS data set. I was trying to tweak it further to predict the path for a simple sample, which i want to use for the  data set i am using with the following code

```
import numpy as np

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

iris = load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target
X_train=np.array(X)
y_train=np.array(y)
X_test=np.array([[ 5.8,  2.8,  5.1,  2.4]])
estimator = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_leaf_nodes=3, random_state=0)
estimator.fit(X_train, y_train)

# The decision estimator has an attribute called tree_  which stores entire
# tree structure and allows access to low level attributes. The binary tree
# Some of the arrays only apply to either leaves or split nodes, resp. In this
# case the values of nodes of the other type are arbitrary!
#
# Among those arrays, we have:
#   - left_child, id of the left child of the node
#   - right_child, id of the right child of the node
#   - feature, feature used for splitting the node
#   - threshold, threshold value at the node
#

# Using those arrays, we can parse the tree structure:
n_nodes = estimator.tree_.node_count
children_left = estimator.tree_.children_left
children_right = estimator.tree_.children_right
feature = estimator.tree_.feature
threshold = estimator.tree_.threshold


# The tree structure can be traversed to compute various properties such
# as the depth of each node and whether or not it is a leaf.
node_depth = np.zeros(shape=n_nodes)
is_leaves = np.zeros(shape=n_nodes, dtype=bool)
stack = [(0, -1)]  # seed is the root node id and its parent depth
while len(stack) > 0:
    node_id, parent_depth = stack.pop()
    node_depth[node_id] = parent_depth + 1

# If we have a test node
    if (children_left[node_id] != children_right[node_id]):
        stack.append((children_left[node_id], parent_depth + 1))
        stack.append((children_right[node_id], parent_depth + 1))
    else:
        is_leaves[node_id] = True

print("The binary tree structure has %s nodes and has the following tree :" %     
for i in range(n_nodes):
    if is_leaves[i]:
        print("%snode=%s leaf node." % (node_depth[i] * "\t", i))
    else:
        print("%snode=%s test node: go to node %s if X[:, %s] <= %ss else to "
              "node %s."
              % (node_depth[i] * "\t",
                 i,
                 children_left[i],
                 feature[i],
                 threshold[i],
                 children_right[i],
                 ))
print()

# First let's retrieve the decision path of each sample. The decision_path
# method allows to retrieve the node indicator functions. A non zero element      
# indicator matrix at the position (i, j) indicates that the sample i goes
# through the node j.

node_indicator = estimator.decision_path(X_test)

# Similarly, we can also have the leaves ids reached by each sample.

leave_id = estimator.apply(X_test)

# Now, it's possible to get the tests that were used to predict a sample or
# a group of samples. First, let's make it for the sample.

sample_id = 0
node_index = node_indicator.indices[node_indicator.indptr[sample_id]:
                                node_indicator.indptr[sample_id + 1]]

print('Rules used to predict sample %s: ' % sample_id)
print(node_index)
for node_id in node_index:
    if leave_id[sample_id] != node_id:
        continue

    if (X_test[sample_id, feature[node_id]] <= threshold[node_id]):
        threshold_sign = "<="
    else:
        threshold_sign = ">"
    print (node_id,sample_id,feature[node_id],i)

    print("decision id node %s : (X[%s, %s] (= %s) %s %s)"
          % (node_id,
             sample_id,
             feature[node_id],
             X_test[i, feature[node_id]],
             threshold_sign,
             threshold[node_id]))

# For a group of samples, we have the following common node.
sample_ids = [0, 1]
common_nodes = (node_indicator.toarray()[sample_ids].sum(axis=0) ==
            len(sample_ids))

common_node_id = np.arange(n_nodes)[common_nodes]

print("\nThe following samples %s share the node %s in the tree"
  % (sample_ids, common_node_id))
print("It is %s %% of all nodes." % (100 * len(common_node_id) / n_nodes,))

It gives the following error


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-3601a3ae5652> in <module>()
    111              sample_id,
    112              feature[node_id],
--> 113              X_test[i, feature[node_id]],
    114              threshold_sign,
    115              threshold[node_id]))

IndexError: index 4 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1
```

The problem here is the code is trying to take X_test[4,-2], which is obviously out of index. Can someone help in understanding how i can tweak this to predict the rule for a single sample?

Comment: Too much code, please provide a [Minimum, Complete and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: @vmg , im trying the same code as in http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/tree/plot_unveil_tree_structure.html# . you can run it directly. Only change is instead of a large number of test samples as in original code, im trying to predict the tree for a single sample, as you see my X_test contains only one sample.

Comment: Yes, thats a typo. Instead of `X_test[i, feature[node_id]]`, it should be `X_test[sample_id, feature[node_id]]`, which is used just above to it to represent the index in print function.

Comment: Its been corrected in the master branch of scikit-learn. You can see the [corrected one here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/examples/tree/plot_unveil_tree_structure.py).

Comment: @VivekKumar Thanks a lot Vivek for your help with this. I spent lot of time searching on this, strangely couldn't find anything on this. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: @VivekKumar One more question if you can help with. I tried searching a lot couldn't find anything useful. Not sure if im missing anything or some issue with the code. Whenever i try looking for reason led to a particular prediction, it gives a one line response

Comment: I am not understanding. Can you explain in a bit more detail, with the samples and code output if any

Comment: Rules used to predict sample 0: 
decision id node 60762 : (X_test[0, -2] (= 2.0) > -2.0)     , what i was expecting is the complete the path from root till leaf. I am doing it in a different way by extracting Node indicators and parsing the actual tree, but want to check if there is easier way with original code

Comment: @VivekKumar  I am trying to print the complete path a sample taken in decision tree. I can do it by parsing node_indicator with the with the complete tree printed by this code. But what i thought was the scikit learn code starting with print('Rules used to predict sample %s: ' % sample_id)                         will do the same, however it always print a one line as in                              Rules used to predict sample 0: decision id node 60762 : (X_test[0, -2] (= 2.0) > -2.0)                              and not the path a sample took in the tree

Comment: Because thats the only line printed in the for loop below it. To print the complete path, you need to change the code like the part, where the tree structure is coded, in the given tutorial.

Comment: @VivekKumar Thanks a lot Vivek for helping with this. It prints the complete tree after commenting first two lines in the for loop                                        if leave_id[sample_id] != node_id:
        continue                                                                                                  Thanks  a lot for your help with this.